# Apostrophe and Quotation in PostgreSQL -How to replace Apostrophe?

Tags: sql, postgresql, syntax, case-sensitive

Which are the roles in a query string of `apostrophe` and `quotation mark` in SQL? How can the `apostrophe` be replaced?

Main interest is their specific roles in PostgreSQL.

Leaving `apostrophe` out messes SQL query, e.g,:

```
SELECT role FROM "USER_ROLES" WHERE "USER_ROLES".login = admin;
```

Gets a 'column' admin does not exist error, when admin is a value. Writing **'admin'** corrects the problem:

```
SELECT role FROM "USER_ROLES" WHERE "USER_ROLES".login = 'admin';
```

Actual problem is using the query in another context:

```
<module-option name="rolesQuery" value="SELECT 'role', 'Roles' FROM &quot;USER_ROLES&quot; WHERE login='?'"/>
```

As requested, table definition is:

```
CREATE TABLE "USER_ROLES" (
  login text NOT NULL,
  role text,
  CONSTRAINT "USER_ROLES_pkey" PRIMARY KEY (login ),
  CONSTRAINT "USER_ROLES_login_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (login)
      REFERENCES "USER" (login) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

PostgreSQL version 9.1.

Comment: Please show your exact **table definition** so we know whether identifiers are actually upper-case letters. Also your version of PostgreSQL.

Comment: There is no column "ROLES" in your table?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can replace **single-quotes** (`'`) with [**dollar-quoting**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING) in PostgreSQL to avoid their special meaning in a different context. (Not sure, though, whether the dollar-sign has a special meaning, too):

```
<module-option name="rolesQuery" value="SELECT role FROM &quot;USER_ROLES&quot; WHERE login = $$?$$"/>
```

The other idea would be to use `&apos;` in place of single-quotes:

```
<module-option name="rolesQuery" value="SELECT role FROM &quot;USER_ROLES&quot; WHERE login = &apos;?&apos;"/>
```

Comment: And once you're using dollar-quoting in place of single quotes, you could likely use single quotes rather than double quotes around the entire SQL string allowing double quotes to be used directly when those are needed.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT role FROM "USER_ROLES" WHERE "USER_ROLES".login = 'admin';
```

This single quotes refers to the string.
When ever you are trying to do operations over the string directly these quotes are required.
Other than like if you are dealing with the String object then there is no need of quotes, you can use the object directly.

As you are using Single quotes(') for referring string in column directly, The double quotes(") are used to refer the table object. (You can refer the table name directly without any quotes)

**Expanded:**

```
SELECT role FROM "USER_ROLES" WHERE "USER_ROLES".login = 'admin';
```

Here 'admin' is a direct string and it is the value of one cell in the respective column.

```
var string_object = 'admin';
SELECT role FROM "USER_ROLES" WHERE "USER_ROLES".login = string_object;
```

Here string_object is the object in which some string is stored and that stored string represents the value of one cell in the respective column.

Comment: Good, still can't include that query on an XML file

Answer (score 2):

**The single apostrophe (`'`) is used for strings.**

When you omit the apostophes, the interpreter will see it as a name, and try to find a value associated with that name (usually a column).

So invalid:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE yourcolumn = xyz -- fails because there is no column named xyz
                       -- also, if it would exist, it would compare to the
                       -- value in that column rather than to the value 'xyz'
```

And valid:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE yourcolumn = 'xyz'
```

**The quotation mark (`"`) is used for names in the database.**

The reason for this is that PostgreSQL does not accept capital letters in your table names (and column names, etc.) unless if you put them in quotes. You are also allowed to put them around lowercase names, in which case there is no difference. Also, this allows you to use reserved names as table- or column names. So `"index"` can be used a a column name, because the quotation marks indicate a name. Using `index` without the quotation marks indicates the reserved word for handling indexes.

So, this is invalid:

```
SELECT index -- invalid, reserved name
FROM YourTable -- invalid, capital letters
```

And this is valid:

```
SELECT "index"
FROM "YourTable"
```

Comment: Is there a way to avoid the '' in a value?

Comment: So the question is actually about jboss configuration? For the double quotes, can't you escape them? And for the '?', can't you just omit the quotes? Normal systems that accept your parameters this way include whatever is needed (such as single quotes and escaping the value not to break the query) depending on the type of the value you provide.

Comment: Though, I have worked with a system that did not allow me to use capital letters not rescape the table name. Either remname your table, or create methods/views with lower case.

Answer (score 0):

you can replace apostrophe by adding another apostrophe to it.

```
select replace('hi''','''','m')--  replaces apostrophe with m.
```